# Wrong offset timezone calculation for multiple clocks in Windows 10 (1903)

Tags: windows-10, time-zone

I'm trying to have more than one clock on my windows taskbar but I've encountered a problem that I've never seen and I can't find anything about it on the net.

I live in Uruguay and my timezone is UTC-3 but since I work with Guatemala I've added a new additional clock for that timezone that is UTC-6.
I've added that clock but the time offset is not properly calculated! This is crazy.. here in Uruguay is 9:30 am and in Guatemala's clock I'm seeing 7:30! when it should be 6:30 am (UTC-3 vs UTC-6 are 3 hours!).
So I've tried to add a new timezone, Santiago timezone (that is UTC-4) and Windows is showing me the same hour than Uruguay! 
What is going on??
Below is a screenshot of the whole information.

[image: Here's a screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering my own question.

I fix my problem talking with one of my Guatemala's coworkers! The problem is that `Central Time` contains a daylight saving time that `Central America` doesn't and that's the problem.. Windows shows for both timezones UTC-6 but one has a daylight saving time and the other doesn't. So I've used `Central America`.